# Can I have multiple babel.config.js in a monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, monorepo

I have a monorepo with the structure like below

```
babel.config.js
packages/
|---mobile/
   |----package.json
   |----src/index.js

|---desktop/
   |----package.json
   |----src/index.js

|---server/
   |----package.json
   |----src/index.js
```

So my `babel` configuration for `mobile` and `desktop` packages are same, whereas configuration for `server`package is different.

Now, how can I have that configuration done? One solution, that I can think of is that to have a `babel.config.js` at the root of monorepo which would have configurations for `mobile` and `desktop` packages and a separate configuration for `server` package in a `babel.config.js` at `server` package level.  I am not sure, can we even have multiple `babel.config.js`.

Comment: Do you actually want separate files, or are you just asking how to have different configurations for different subfolders? If one file is fine, you can use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#overrides in the root folder.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I am asking to have different configurations for different subfolders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think using separate files would lead to confusion. Assuming you've set up your system in a way that works already and you're just asking how to specify different configs for different locations, you can use the [`"overrides"`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#overrides) option. For example, your config can do

```
module.exports = {
  overrides: [{
    test: [
      './desktop',
      './mobile',
    ],

    // put all your normal babel options for these folders here
  }, {
    test: [
      './server',
    ],

    // put all your normal babel options for the server here
  }],
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can achieve what you asked by having multiple config files. It is mentioned as File-relative configuration in babel documentation.

Create a .babelrc or .babelrc.js file in each of your directories (mobile, desktop, server)

For more details look at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/config-files